# Problem to connect ssh in a cisco device using netmiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, cisco-ios

I am trying to connect into a cisco device using netmiko, but I am facing the error bellow: I tried to change my code but didnt work at all.

```
    from netmiko import ConnectHandler

    cisco ={
     'device_type':  'cisco_ios',
     'ip': ' 192.168.1.1',
     'username': 'cisco',
     'password': 'cisco',
    }

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco)
output = net_connect.send_command('show ip inter brief')
print(output)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/rdc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py",
>   line 782, in establish_connection
>       self.remote_conn_pre.connect(**ssh_connect_params)   File "/home/rdc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py",
>   line 334, in connect
>       to_try = list(self._families_and_addresses(hostname, port))   File "/home/rdc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py",
>   line 204, in _families_and_addresses
>       hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
>       for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags): socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/rdc/Documents/connection.py", line 10, in 
>       net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco)   File "/home/rdc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py",
>   line 218, in ConnectHandler
>       return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/rdc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py",
>   line 270, in **init**
>       self.establish_connection()   File "/home/rdc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py",
>   line 787, in establish_connection
>       raise NetMikoTimeoutException(msg) netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoTimeoutException: Connection to device
>   timed-out: cisco_ios  192.168.1.1:22
>
> > > >

Answer (score 0):

I think this part of the exception explains what the problem is:

```
netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoTimeoutException: Connection to device timed-out: cisco_ios 192.168.1.1:22
```

What happens when you try to SSH to 192.168.1.1 from the same machine? Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code :

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from getpass import getpass


cisco_Router = {
    "device_type": "cisco_ios",
    "host": "router01",
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password"}

with ConnectHandler(**cisco_Router) as net_connect:

    result = net_connect.send_command('show ip inter brief')
    net_connect.disconnect()

print(result)
```